# How to change action bar's color by button?

Tags: java, android

I want to save the color by clicking the button and set this color on others activities.

I use code to change it but this code doesn't save the color. What should I add in my code?

```
mYellowColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
                ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.yello)));
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can store colour hex code to Shared Preferences or DB and then pull hex code at other activities.

Comment: How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Shared Preferences in your class

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

Inside onCreate add

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And then inside onClickListener

```
        mYellowColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    String hexColor = "ADD YOUR HEX CODE HERE";
                    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexColor)));
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("toolbarColor",hexColor);
                    editor.commit();

                    }
                });
```

On next activity again define Shared Preferences and add following code to onCreate

```
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ShaPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String hexColor = sharedPreferences.getString("toolbarColor", "");
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(hexColor)));
```